# ODO cannot access S3 with S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, boto3, odo

I am using odo library to transfer a **pandas dataframe** to S3. However I am getting following error :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=["A", "B"])
odo(df,'s3://path_to_s3_folder')
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Anonymous access is forbidden for this operation</Message><RequestId>F5958774D56AD29E</RequestId><HostId>zOH8JOxpSgB5Scgc/YrtHO1+e9lXoKAF89IhRSeAiSoGHAJxyjXKBVFIYETeO4gSLZOUgXmwKLM=</HostId></Error>
```

Now I have the AWS credentials setup correctly as I can see in my `~/.aws/credentials` file

```
cat credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXX
```

The aws cli works correctly for me and I can run `aws ls` and `cp` commands correctly (I guess this means I do have the required permissions).

```
aws s3 ls s3://path_to_s3
```

Also `boto3` is able to access s3 resources and does not give an error.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

What would be possible wrong/missing in the configuration ?

Comment: It seems odo only talk to boto, not boto3, install boto modules and try again
https://github.com/blaze/odo

Comment: @mootmoot Yes it worked. The issue was in way boto and boto3 gets credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install boto.

After making a quick check on [pandas odo](http://github.com/blaze/odo) source,  the code only uses boto module, it does not support boto3.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @mootmoot, `odo` uses `boto` and **not `boto3`**.

`boto3` can get aws credentials from `~/.aws/credentials` as stated [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration). However for `boto` you need to setup env variable as stated [here](https://github.com/boto/boto#getting-started-with-boto)

Just add,

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXX
```